# Fallo en la automatización de pruebas con behat + selenium

Tags: php, login, docker, selenium, behat

Estos son los tres archivos que componen la prueba de login con behat y selenium
(aparte de ayuda agradecería algunas fuentes fiables donde poder consultar y aprender sobre la creación de pruebas automatizadas con behat y selenium)

```
[behat.yml]
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: https://ruta/a/pagina/de/login    
      selenium2: ~
      browser_name: 'chrome'
      sessions:
        default:
          selenium2:
            wd_host: "http://selenium:4444"
  suites:
    defaults:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext

[archivo.feature]
Feature: Login into the website

  Scenario: Log in as admin
    Given I am on "https://ruta/a/pagina/de/login"
    And I fill in "username" with "admin"
    And I fill in "password" with "admin"
    When I press "submit"
    Then I should be logged in

[FeatureContext.php]

<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */

    /**
     * @Then I should be logged in
     */
    public function iShouldBeLoggedIn()
    {
        $currentUrl = $this->getSession()->getCurrentUrl();
        if ($currentUrl !== "https://melt.docker/my/") {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf("Expected to be on \"https://melt.docker/my/\" but found \"%s\" instead.", $currentUrl));
        }
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar la prueba devuelve el siguiente error

Scenario: Log in as admin                                        # features/prueba.feature:3
Given I am on "https://ruta/a/pagina/login"
Step "I should be logged in" is already defined in FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()

```
  FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
  FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
And I fill in "username" with "admin"
  Step "I should be logged in" is already defined in FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
  
  FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
  FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
And I fill in "password" with "admin"
  Step "I should be logged in" is already defined in FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
  
  FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
  FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
When I press "submit"
  Step "I should be logged in" is already defined in FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
  
  FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
  FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
Then I should be logged in
  Step "I should be logged in" is already defined in FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
  
  FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
  FeatureContext::iShouldBeLoggedIn()
```

--- Failed scenarios:

```
features/prueba.feature:3
```

1 scenario (1 failed)
5 steps (5 failed)
0m0.10s (4.81Mb)

Comment: Hola, estimado no te saldria mas acuenta aprender automatizar con java o python que son lenguajes mas usados actualmente en la actualidad, a mi recomendación te adudaria bastante y seria un plus para cuaquier trabajo.  Saludos.